# Как добавить свое состояние чекбоксу React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Решил изучить реакт, и вот споткнулся...

[Пример](https://codepen.io/sergej-panow/pen/bGExjXZ) того, как я пытался это сделать

```js
 class FormUserItem extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          // Эта привязка обязательна для работы `this` в колбэке.
          this.handleChecked = this.handleChecked.bind(this);
        }

        handleChecked(e) {
          this.props.onChange(e.target);
        }

        render() {
          let className = "user__item";
          if (this.props.isChecked) {
            className += " active";
          }
          return (
              <label>
                <input
                    className={className}
                    name={"usr_"+this.props.id}
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={ this.props.isChecked}
                    onChange={this.handleChecked}
                />
                {this.props.name}
              </label>
          );
        }
      }


      class FormUserItems extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { isChecked: false };

          // Эта привязка обязательна для работы `this` в колбэке.
          this.handleChecked = this.handleChecked.bind(this);
        }

        handleChecked(e) {
          this.setState((state) => {
           return {isChecked:  !state.isChecked}
      
          });
    
        }

        handleSubmit(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

        }

        render() {
          return (
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                { this.props.users.map((user) =>
                    <FormUserItem  key={user.id} name={user.name} isChecked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.handleChecked} id={user.id}/>
                )}
                <div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
                </div>
              </form>

          );
        }
      }

      const users = [
        { id: 1, name: "User-1" },
        { id: 2, name: "User-2" },
        { id: 3, name: "User-3" }
      ];

      ReactDOM.render(<FormUserItems users={users} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Но состояние при клике меняется сразу у всех чекбоксов.

Как в данной логике поставить состояние конкретному чекбоксу?

Или данный подход совсем не верный?

Если так, то приведите пример верного решения, чтобы не применять заведомо неправильный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про [подъем состояния](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) почитайте.

У вас есть родитель - `FormUserItems`, который контролирует сhecked дочерних элементов `FormUserItem` (над названиями поработайте, будете путаться).
В стейте родителя должен храниться стейт с массивом пользователей (в примере users)

Цепочка следующая:

1. Родитель создает чилдрена с чекбоксом, в пропсы которого передает ID и забинженую функцию для изменения СВОЕГО(родительского) стейта.
2. Чилдрены получают функцию и свой ID, при срабатывании эвента onChange чилдрен вызывает забинженную функцию и передает в нее свой ID из пропсов.
3. Забинженая функция, по ID изменяет isChecked юзера, формирует и применяет новый стейт.
4. React перерисовывает измененный элемент (важно! не все элементы, а только измененный).

```js
class FormUserItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let className = "user__item";
        if (this.props.isChecked) {
            className += " active";
        }

        return (
            <label>
                <input
                    className={className}
                    name={"usr_" + this.props.id}
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.props.isChecked}
                    //handleCheck из пропсов берем
                    onChange={() => this.props.handleChecked(this.props.id)}
                />
                {this.props.name}
            </label>
        );
    }
}

class FormUserItems extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //юзеров из пропсов мы сразу определяем в стейт и дальше работаем только со стейтом.
        this.state = {
            users: this.props.users
        };

        this.handleChecked = this.handleChecked.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleChecked(id) {
        let users = this.state.users.slice();
        let user = users.find(user=>user.id == id);
        user.isChecked = !user.isChecked;
        this.setState({users});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                {this.state.users.map((user) => (
                    <FormUserItem
                        key={user.id}
                        name={user.name}
                        isChecked={user.isChecked || false} //если isChecked нет, то поумолчанию он фолс.
                        onChange={this.handleChecked}
                        handleChecked={this.handleChecked}
                        id={user.id}
                    />
                ))}
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}




const users = [
    { id: 1, name: "User-1" },
    { id: 2, name: "User-2" },
    { id: 3, name: "User-3" }
];

ReactDOM.render(
    <FormUserItems users={users} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap');
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.user__item{
  padding:20px 15px;
  background: #0a84ff;
  color:#fff;
  &.active{
    background: #e65e59;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно что бы у каждого из `checkbox`'ов был собственный `state`, тогда при изменении одного из `inpit`'ов остальные меняться не будут.

Пример на хуках:

```
const Input = () => {

   const [state, setState] = useState(false)

   const handleChange = event => {
       setState(prevState => !prevState)
   }

   return (
       <input 
           type="checkbox" 
           onChange={handleChange} 
           checked={state}
          />
   )
}  

const Form = () => {
    return (
       <div>
          <Input />
          <Input />
         </div>
     )
}
```

Вам может подойти [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1155278/397819) пользователя [@xydope](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/368113/xydope), где он наглядно показывает как использовать [подьем состояния](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Имейте ввиду что если Вы стремитесь к созданию максимально переиспользуемых компонентов то решение с одним стейтом в родителе не являться оптимальным.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!Полезная информация и пример!  Я пока только познаю основы основ, но ваше замечание буду иметь ввиду.